# Update table and add new column with check for all rows for UserName numbers | SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need add this script

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
    ADD [MyNewColumnCheckUserName] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

But after the update, I need to check all old rows in `MyTable` - all UserName (it is column in this table) if UserName has only numbers? If yes - set true for this row `MyNewColumnCheckUserName`.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Why would you want a flag on each row that refers to the entire table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
update mytable
    set MyNewColumnCheckUserName = (case when UserName like '%[^0-9]%' then 0 else 1 end);
```

However, I would recommend just adding this as a computed column:

```
alter table mytable add MyNewColumnCheckUserName as 
    (case when UserName like '%[^0-9]%' then 0 else 1 end);
```

There is *no* reason that I know of to prefer a bit instead of a number for a computed column.  But if you really want to incur the overhead of a `bit`, you can convert the value:

```
alter table mytable add MyNewColumnCheckUserName as 
    (convert(bit, (case when UserName like '%[^0-9]%' then 0 else 1 end));
```

Comment: how I can set that it is BIT. Now the table think that it is a number. I need that it will be a BIT @Gordon Linoff